# AutoReconnect connection closed error occurs after some inactive time with pymongo using in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a lambda function written on Python 3.8 in us-east-1 and eu-west-1 regions. Lambda is trying to connect to Mongodb (same db for both regions)
Lambda in us-east-1 region is working fine
Lambda in ew-west-1 region throws AutoReconnect('connection closed')> error
It happens after 15-60 minutes of inactivity. I mean if lambda was not executed for an hour, it would work fine. But if you decide to run it again in 20 minutes it would crush.
Here is my current code:

```
import pymongo
import logging
import os

connectionString = os.environ.get('MONGODBCONNECTIONSTRING')
databaseName = os.environ.get('MONGODBDATABASENAME')
clientMongo = pymongo.MongoClient(connectionString)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        db = getattr(clientMongo, databaseName)
        session_doc = db["_Session"]
        return session_doc.find_one({"_session_token": "123"})
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error(ex)
        return None
```

The error occurs in line

```
      return session_doc.find_one({"_session_token": "123"})
```

Variable session_doc type is collection, but I can not get a row from it
I have tried to wrap it with cycle and try-except, it didn't help, error happened again and again while lambda timeout was not reached

How should I change my code so that this error does not occur?

Answer (score 0):

It was an error with MongoDB whitelist. Lambda had two subnets and one IP address was in the whitelist, but the second one was not. I have added the second IP to the whitelist and it worked for me.